# Proving $\varphi(x^n)=\varphi(x)^n$ is a homomorphism for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I began my proof using induction however I'm a little stuck on understanding what to for my inductive step. I'm looking for proof validation and tips to improve my proof-writing.

Pf:
Let $G$ and $H$ be groups such that $\varphi :G\longrightarrow H$ be a homomorphism. Then we will proceed by mathematical induction to show that $\varphi (x^n)=\varphi (x)^n$ is true for $n=1$.  Then,

$$\varphi (x^n)=\varphi (x)^n \iff \varphi (x^1)= \varphi (x)^1 \iff \varphi(x)=\varphi (x)$$

Then the $\varphi(x^n)=\varphi(x)^n$ is true for the base step.
Next let assume that our inductive hypothesis is that  $\varphi(x^n)=\varphi(x)^n$ is true for $n=k$.

Then we want to show in our inductive step that  $\varphi(x^n)=\varphi(x)^n$ is true for $n=k+1$.
Then 
$$\varphi(x^{k+1})=\varphi(x)^{k+1} \Longleftrightarrow \varphi(x^kx^1)=\varphi(x)^k\varphi(x)^1$$

Now we will multiple both sides by $\varphi(x^{-k})$, then,

\begin{align*}
\varphi(x^kx^1)\varphi(x^{-k})=\varphi(x)^k\varphi(x)^1\varphi(x^{-k})\Longleftrightarrow 
\varphi(x^1)=\varphi(x)^1=\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)
\end{align*}

Thus $\varphi(x^n)=\varphi(x)^n$.

I like to say that what I did is correct but I'm not sure if I can justify exactly what happened in the inductive step.

thanks in advance :)
and thanks to those who helped me edit this!

Comment: Why was this question deleted and re-posted?

Comment: Honestly at first it took awhile to edit it correctly and I was unsure whether it would be answered if I didn't delete the other one and reposted. Might have been unwise I guess

Comment: There is an edit feature, as you might have noticed. When you edit a question you bump it automatically to the top of the front page. Next time, just edit your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to multiply by $\varphi(x^{-k})$. The defining property of homomorphisms is that $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for any $a,b$ in your group. Insert $a=x^k$ and $b=x$, and you're (almost) done.

That being said, I feel that your last $\iff$ skipped a few steps. It's correct, certainly, but if I were a teacher correcting this, I would say that you missed a huge opportunity to demonstrate that you actually can use the homomorphism property in a calculation (which is half the point of this exercise, the other half being practicing induction). You've just started at the beginning and jumped right to the end in a single step.

Finally, a matter of personal taste: wherever possible, I would prefer a long chain of equalities beginning with $\varphi(x^{k+1})$ and ending in $\varphi(x)^{k+1}$ to a long chain of $\iff$'s beginning with what you want to prove and ending with something trivial. If you do it your way, at least have one equality (with a single $=$) on each line instead of writing them out in one long line. Then it's easier to follow, and you don't really need the $\iff$'s.

Comment: I believe I was able to arrive at $\varphi(x)^{k+1}$ now with. $\varphi(x^{k+1})=\varphi(x^kx)=\varphi(x^k)\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)^k\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)^{k+1}$. Is this much better?

Comment: That looks perfect. You could explain $=$ number 2 and 3 if you wanted to (one is the homomorphism property and the other is induction hypothesis), but I don't personally think that's necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it exactly and I would like to know. Is it just a property of isomorphisms and that's why I can use it? Or is it just because It is true for n=1 and n=k we know that it works?

Comment: @dls No, you don't need more than that.  Something like "$\varphi(x^{k+1})=\varphi(x^kx)$. By the definition of homomorphism this equals $\varphi(x^k)\varphi(x)$, which by the induction hypothesis is equal to $\varphi(x)^k\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)^{k+1}$." is plenty. And as I said, even this might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You have to prove $\varphi(x^{k+1})=\varphi(x)^{k+1}$ with the induction assumption $\varphi(x^{k})=\varphi(x)^{k}$

So you start with $$\phi(x^{k+1})=\phi(x^kx^1)=\cdots(\because \phi \;\text{is a } \cdots)=\cdots(\because \text{by induction})=\phi(x)^{k+1}$$